# Unabel to find @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication in Spring boot (Eclipse)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was using spring boot 1.1.6 earlier, in my new project I tried to use the latest 1.5.4 release but I could not find @EnableAutoConfiguration or @SpringBootApplication to add to my main class. I could find the spring boot auto configure jar in classpath. Can someone please explain how to configure spring boot with the latest release (1.5.4)?

Comment: have you tried the starter projects page? it generated the maven/gradle file for you.

Comment: can you add your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: This is a great place to create new Spring Boot projects: http://start.spring.io/

Answer (score -1):

Spring Boot provides a convenient **@SpringBootApplication** alternative.

The **@SpringBootApplication** annotation is equivalent to using  @Configuration, **@EnableAutoConfiguration** and **@ComponentScan** with their default attributes: [...]